# Linking to anchor tags with will_paginate in Rails 3.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am creating a web forum.  There is a page with a list of threads on it, and the name of each thread links to a page with posts about that thread.

On the threads page I would like to be able to link to the last post in the thread. Each post has a number at the top of it corresponding to the order in which it was created.  The number is an anchor.

The code I have works perfectly and the 'last post' link on the threads page goes right to the correct post on the posts page...unless the post is beyond the first page of posts.  I can't get the '?page=x' part of the URL to appear.

All my research seems to indicate that [this](http://perezj.blogspot.com/2008/06/ruby-on-rails-willpaginate-anchor-param.html) is the way to get the will_paginate gem to pass the page parameter.  However, it does not seem to be working in my project.

This is my actual pagination code on the posts page:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:anchor => i} %>
```

where 'i' is the variable that represents the post numbers.

I am not sure if there is a new way of doing this with the most recent version of will_paginate, or if I am missing something.

EDIT

Here is the code where the anchors are created on the posts page(I do have some nested routes going on):

```
<%= link_to(i, subject_topic_path(@subject, @topic, :anchor => i), {:name => i}) %>
```

And here is the code on the threads page that links to the anchor(it's part of a for statement):

```
      <%= link_to "Last Post Created:", subject_topic_path(s.subject, s, :anchor => s.posts.count)%>
```

Comment: Can you post more code, surrounding block perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, you don't need to get the ?page=x part to show up for page 1. Will paginate will treat :page => nil the same as :page => 1, so unless you have a specific reason to show that:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

will work just fine.

Comment: When the anchor I need to link to is on page one, it works.  My problem is for anchors on page 2 and beyond.  I thought the :anchor tag in the will_paginate call was the way to allow linking to anchors that might be on any page.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure I fully understand what you are expecting vs what errors you are experiencing. If you can try to be very specific on the question, I will re-write my answer for you :)

Comment: Basically, I would like to link to something on a paginated page.  The link might be on page one of that page, or page 35.  I am unable to link to anything beyond page one.  When the link is beyond page one I need the URL to read url?page=x#anchor as opposed to just url#anchor.  I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by passing the :page parameter where I link to the last post.  So it is:

```
      <%= link_to "Last Post Created:", subject_topic_path(s.subject, s, :page => x, :anchor => s.posts.count)%>
```

It now always displays the page in the URL.  As Andrew pointed out this is not necessary for links on page one and a little undesirable, but the links work so I will take it.  The bigger problem is that I needed to put the ruby code where I figure out what 'x' is in the view.  Yuck.

I feel like there is a better way to to do this...but this will serve for the meantime.